# Image Processing: Select the same color at closest distance of an image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image as following, the question is how can I use python select the same color in the closest distance at a special point?

[image]

more specificlly: When I click the point(x, y), I want to select the  region which have the same color. Just like the Photoshop -> Magic wand.

Comment: You want something like selecting a contiguous region, I guess? Don't really know Numpy, but unless it does implement such a thing, you'll have to do it by yourself, like with a propagation algorithm. Something like <a href+"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm">A* algorithm</a> could give you some ideas (though A* algorithm is not designed to discover a contiguous region, but to find the shortest path).

Comment: @Rightleg Thanks for your hint and I will try to understand the A* algorithm.

Comment: I guess you are talking about finding connected component with additional constraint that color of connected pixels should be close. This will do it on whole image automatically but since you want to select the point manually I guess floodfill is the best option for you  [floodFill](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill)